# How to update First object using Second object by maching some values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object

I have two Objects - **listOfStudents** and **homeworkResults**. 
I need to update **listOfStudents** Object using matching by **email**.
So somehow I need do compare this two Objects and **email** is equal - get **topic** and **success** and update **listOfStudents**.
The goal is to use only Javascript.

The result should be next:

```
name: 'John',
email: 'john@gmail.com',
results: [
        {
            topic: 'HTML Basics',
            success: true
        },
        {
            topic: 'CSS Basics',
            success: false
        }
]
```

```
const listOfStudents = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        email: 'john@gmail.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jane',
        email: 'jane@gmail.com'
    }
];

const homeworkResults = [
    {
        topic: 'HTML Basics',
        results: [
            {
                email: 'john@gmail.com',
                success: true
            },
            {
                email: 'jane@gmail.com',
                success: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        topic: 'CSS Basics',
        results: [
            {
                email: 'john@gmail.com',
                success: false
            },
            {
                email: 'jane@gmail.com',
                success: true
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Looks like an assignment - show what you got, where you got stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` on `listOfStudents`. While creating the `results` use `reduce` on `homeworkResults. Inside the callback use`find`to find the object where the email matches. Then from that object take the`success` and topics

```js
const listOfStudents = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    email: 'jane@gmail.com'
  }
];

const homeworkResults = [{
    topic: 'HTML Basics',
    results: [{
        email: 'john@gmail.com',
        success: true
      },
      {
        email: 'jane@gmail.com',
        success: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    topic: 'CSS Basics',
    results: [{
        email: 'john@gmail.com',
        success: false
      },
      {
        email: 'jane@gmail.com',
        success: true
      }
    ]
  }
];
// map will give an array
let data = listOfStudents.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    name: item.name,
    email: item.email,
    // inside reduce callback use find to get the object where 
    // the id matches. If id match then get the topic and success
    results: homeworkResults.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const resultByEmail = curr.results.find(elem => elem.email === item.email);
      acc.push({
        topics: curr.topic,
        success: resultByEmail.success
      })

      return acc;
    }, [])

  }
});

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let i = 0, i < listOfStudents.length ; i++ )
{
var homeworksForSpecificStudent =  homeworkResults.results.filter(x=> x.email == listOfStudents[i].email);
// homeworksForSpecificStudent will be an array with all homeworks with matching emails
// do you operation to modify elements of the list
}
```

Comment: There's an error in your for loop and, I'm always confused when people use arrow functions and *still* have `var`. Also, prefer '===' over '==' unless you have very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm mapping `listOfStudent` and inside that mapping `homeworkResult` and getting the filtered and modified data out of it.

```js
var listOfStudents = [ { name: 'John', email: 'john@gmail.com' }, { name: 'Jane', email: 'jane@gmail.com' }];

var homeworkResults = [ { topic: 'HTML Basics', results: [ { email: 'john@gmail.com', success: true }, { email: 'jane@gmail.com', success: true } ] }, { topic: 'CSS Basics', results: [ { email: 'john@gmail.com', success: false }, { email: 'jane@gmail.com', success: true } ] }];

var result = listOfStudents.map(val=>{
    result = homeworkResults.map(({topic, results})=>({topic,...results.filter(v=>v.email==val.email).map(d=>({success:d.success}))[0]}));
    return {...val, result}
});

console.log(result);
```